# Why is iterating over 60,000 records on SqlDataReader slow?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am working on application optimization, I have optimized my query to take just 5 ms (Total Execution time = ~350 ms) from 17+ secs. But iterating over the SQLDataReader records for **60k** records takes about **900 ms**. Is there any way I can reduce the 900 ms time?

Here is the sample code I used...

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=XXX;initial catalog=XXX;integrated security=True");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspOptimizedSP", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
while (reader.Read())
{
++i;

}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // This results in ~900 ms
```

Elapsed Milliseconds is from **800ms to 950ms**

**Other details**

- Data Set Size = 714 MB for 60k records.
- I have used AutoMapper but it is taking 3+ seconds to convert data from IDataReader to POCO class

Comment: Why don't you use one query to calculate what you want to calculate here? Or, if you want to consume 60000 records, why? Nobody wants to read so many records at one go.

Comment: How fast is you network connection -- transferring 700 MB over most broadband won't be a quick process. It has to transmit everything in your datareader loop.

Comment: It's likely most of the time is network latency/transfer time. It's fast on the local server to complete the query/compute the result set, but physically sending the data over the wire takes real time.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned the Total Execution Time. Its roughly 340 ms.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why does iterating over so many records need to be faster than 900ms?

Comment: Just to meet some internal SLAs.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, they are not for display purposes. I retrieve 60K records but filter them in application to about 6k records. I tried doing this in SQL but it was way too expensive.

Comment: Can you please clarify "from 800ms to 950 sec"? If you handle ~1GB/60K records a second I don't see anything seriously wrong with it...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov 800-900 ms is the time retrieved from the StopWatch.

Comment: @Rwiti: paging and filtering in database is always more efficient than filtering somewhere else(Joel Coehoorns comment). You just have to use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @Silvermind Simply iterating over 60K records in a loop, takes about 4-5 ms but when doing the same in a SqlDataReader its taking about 1 sec.

Comment: @Rwiti: Don't use loops in sql if you can use set based approaches (queries).

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you please tell me what do you mean by loops in SQL? Do you mean loop on the SQLDataReader? Can it be avoided?

Comment: @Rwiti can you give more details on the whole issue you are trying to solve? Getting 60k records from sql and filtering it out to 6k using code sounds insane to me. Also There is SqlBulkCopy that fits better task of coping huge amount of rows to and from sql server.

Comment: @Rwiti: You mentioned _loops_ in your last comment as opposed to using the `SqlDataReader`. So i've assumed that you mean loops in t-sql which should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Rwiti it means don't use cursors and use select/update/insert queries instead.

Comment: @Rwiti Can you please add your "expensive" code that filters out 90 per cent of records on the client, most likely you can do it with sql.

Comment: @vittore you have to trust me on this. I spent a lot of time with my DBA and can't find a better way in SQL.

Comment: @Rwiti I'm still curious to see that

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn if I understand you correctly, do you mean that every iteration is causing a Network Round trip and thats why its slow?

Comment: Let's see, 714 MB in 900ms is a throughput of at least 6.3Gbs.  Do you really expect your network to be faster than that?!?  This is almost entirely a network bandwidth limitation.  The only way to make this reliably faster will be to cut down the amount of data that you are trying to move.

Comment: @RBarryYoung .. very right. The thing I was missing was that ~1 sec loop iteration also included the Network Latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Datareader` reads the data as if it were a stream, retrieving the rows from the database as they become available by the executing query. That is probably why it takes time sice you are copying 714 MB of data. You can not compare it to iterating over an in memory collection.

Comment: Does it mean that every iteration in the loop results in a Network Round Trip ?

Comment: It will not "call" the database but rather just read data from an open stream of rows.

Comment: +1. @Rwiti, not on every iteration, but iterating over all records will read all 750MB of the data from DB over network for all 60K rows.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok, so this means the ~1 sec loop iteration time can not be reduced by any means?

Comment: @Rwiti Think of it like you were reading a file from a Network stream. Copying the data from the database to the client will take time and using a `DataReader` is probably the fastest way of doing it (that I know of)

Comment: @Rwiti -There are always ways to make code faster... I.e. hire good DBA... it will likely be cheaper that fiber-optic network to send so data faster...